# How to use the set gap of the Grid column and not based on the length of an item in the Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to have the last item in the 1st column to just have the set gap of the Grid. And not be pushed down so much because of the length of the last item in the 2nd column. How do I achieve this? [Grid column of my services where I show my desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Repyr.png)

Comment: A grid is a grid – everything is arranged in **rows and columns**. To achieve what you want, you can either use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`, or you can use [**columns**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp). ([columns example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053186/2518285))